# How do I resize an anchor image in css?

Tags: html, css

I have an image that is also a link to another page, but the picture is way too big. I tried to make it 40% smaller by making the `shirt-pic` class's width 40% smaller, it didn't work.

```
<a class="shirt-pic" href="pages/original.html"><img src="images/original.png" alt="shirt"/></a>

.shirt-pic {
    width:40%
    height: auto;
}
```

Also, I have centered my logo image link at the top of the screen and its too big, I need to resize that too, but I am already using the width property to center it because w3 schools said to set it to 50% for it to work.

```
<span id="brand-logo"><a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="Logo"/></a></span>

#brand-logo {
    display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 50%;
    background-color: FFFFFF;
}
```

Should I just resize it in the html? Is there no way to do it with css?

Comment: `width:50%` to center an element? I have never heard of such a thing.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_center.asp

Comment: Here is the link to where they tell you do do that, look up "how to center image css" and its the first link that pops up

Comment: I tried applying the img targeting method to the logo and its already causing problems lol I might have to use flex or something

Comment: The sample above has nothing important about the width 50%. The secret for centering an element is to set the `margin:auto` (with any desired width).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anchor tags have a default display type of `inline`, so you can't directly size them. You can target the image though:

```css
.shirt-pic img {
    width: 40%;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<a class="shirt-pic" href="pages/original.html"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/1oG1X.jpg" alt="shirt"/></a>
```

Comment: If you click "Run code snippet", you can see that it's working

Comment: Thanks, yeah I validated my css and fixed it

Answer (score 2):

```
<a href="pages/original.html"><img class="shirt-pic" src="images/original.png" alt="shirt"/></a>
```

you need give class in image

```
.shirt-pic {
    width:200px;
    height: auto;
}
```

or

```
<a class="shirt-pic" href="pages/original.html"><img src="images/original.png" alt="shirt"/></a>

.shirt-pic img{
    width:40%
    height: auto;
}
```